# My slackapp not working on other workspaces

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

My slack app is working perfectly fine on my workspace but when I try to install in on other workspaces, the home tab says "work still in progress".

I have tried different permissions one by one but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of where it is working and where it does not?
Also add payload received, when home page is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The "Work in progress" error could mean that you are not passing the correct user id in your `views.publish` call. Perhaps you are hard-coding the user id from your initial Workspace? Keep in mind that your user id is different in each Workspace. You will also need to extract the user id dynamically in order for other users to see the App Home content.

The best practice here would be to use the Events API and listen for the `app_home_opened` event. With the response from this event you can then use the `user_id` to display the view in the App Home for each user that accesses it.

https://api.slack.com/surfaces/tabs/events

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! It was exactly the reason in my case: user ID was hard-coded and was the same for all users. That's why other users saw "Work in progress" message in App Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an app under an workspace you can use the current workspace to develop and test the app under all the circumstances.

However, if you want to port or install you Slack app in another workspace you need to install the app in the workspace using the app installation credentials from that workspace. To be specific of your App Home showing 'Work under progress' there may be a few reasons why that shows up:

1. Check the values of bot token, user id and view payload modal used under the `views.publish` method.
2. Toggle the Home Tab on and off, then **re-install the app** to workspace.
3. **Check the installation parameters** of your Slack Application in the new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the workspace bot token from auth flow and use that to authenticate when calling the views.publish endpoint.